# Multiple documents from a single dtx

Tags: package-writing, dtx

The DTX format allows to generate both the package code (`.sty` file) and documentation (`.pdf` file) from a single dtx file.

Is it possible to generate several PDFs (for example for different languages) from a single dtx file?

Comment: I think `dtx` is good for producing multiple package files, but it will require a lot of work to maintain multiple document files similarly, because you will have to use `<*option> … </option>` everywhere. I'd go with a different approach.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My answers is split in two parts: first I show how DTX files, i.e. docstrip tags, can be used to extract different parts for different language and then I discuss the issue that you have in a real DTX file for a package.

In general you can use the docstrip tags `<*lang1>` ... `</lang1>` to mark all file sections which contain the text for the first language etc., e.g. `<*de>` .. `</de>` for German. Then use a INS file (as you should already have for your DTX file) to extract this parts to a TEX file which can then be compiled separately. A "DTX" file which only holds these texts would look something like:

```
<*en>
 Hello!
</en>
<*de>
 Hallo!
</de>
<*klingon>
 Qapla’!
</klingon>
Common part
```

Then have a INS file like this:

```
\input docstrip.tex
\generate{%
  \file{<name>-en.tex}{\from{<name>.dtx}{en}}%
  \file{<name>-de.tex}{\from{<name>.dtx}{de}}%
  \file{<name>-klingon.tex}{\from{<name>.dtx}{klingon}}%
}
```

And compile it as follows:

```
tex <name>.ins
latex <name>-en
latex <name>-de
latex <name>-klingon
```

---

*However*, note that the normal documentation in a DTX file is commented out, so that it is not (and cannot) be extracted. If you want to have multiple languages in one DTX file you could use some if-switches in the documentation part and then have a small wrapper which sets this if-switch accordantly.
I did something like this for my `adjustbox` package.

There I have at the beginning of the DTX file, just before `\documentclass` the following code which define the if-switch if it doesn't exists and sets it to true:

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname ifenglish\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\newif\csname ifenglish\endcsname
    \englishtrue
\fi
```

In the document I use it like this:

```
\ifenglish
   Do you wish a cup of tea?    % (British) English
\else
   Wie willst du deinen Kaffee? % German (we drink coffee!)
\fi
```

Then at the end I have the following wrapper code which sets the if-switch to *false* which enables the German parts and simply inputs the DTX file. For this to work you need to use an explicit name in `\DocInput{<name>.dtx}` and not `\jobname`.

```
% \iffalse
%<*de>
%% Wrapper to set language to German.
\expandafter\newif\csname ifenglish\endcsname
\englishfalse
\input{adjustbox.dtx}
%</de>
% \fi
```

The INS file contains instructions to extract this to to a TEX file:

```
\input docstrip.tex
\generate{%
  \file{<name>.sty}{\from{<name>.dtx}{<name>.sty}}%
  \file{<name>-de.tex}{\from{<name>.dtx}{de}}%
}
```

Then to compile the manual in English run `latex <name>.dtx`, to extract the STY and other TEX file use: `tex <name>.ins` and then `latex <name>-de` to compile the German manual.

Comment: Thanks for including Klingon in your example, that's exactly the language I wanted to write documentation for!

Comment: @Raphink: The Vulcans will be disappointed if you don't include them :-)

Comment: For the record, I will accept the answer as soon as I find the time to test and apply it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.dtx` file to generate several `.tex` files, and compile them separately. Then you'll get multiple documents.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on this?

Comment: @N.N. Martin has done for that. After all, it is not very difficult to do that for package developers. My answer is more a notation than a full solution.